# Inline rails form field with button

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails form in which I can add more fields dynamically with the following javascript.

```
<%= form_for(@service, url: services_create_path) do |form| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.text_field :name, autofocus: true, :class=>"form-control", :placeholder=>"Service name" %><a href="javascript:;" id="addNewService" style="text-decoration: none;">Add more services</a>
  </div>

  <div id="serviceSet"></div>

  <div class="form-group">
     <%= form.submit :class=>"btn btn-primary pull-right" %>
  </div>
<% end %>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addNewService').click(function(){
        $('div#serviceSet').append('<div class ="new_service"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="display: inline-block;" placeholder="enter more services">'+

            '<button class="btn btn-default" style="display: inline-block;" type="button">remove</button></div>' + '<br>'

        );
    });

    $("div#serviceSet").on('click', '.btn', function(){
        $(this).closest('.new_service').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Right now the `remove` button shows under the newly added form filed as you see:

[image]

How can I inline the form field along with the button?

Comment: Are you using some CSS framework? those doesn't look like the default styles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ arieljuod... I'm using bootstrap styles on my app

Comment: Check the docs for input groups https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/#button-addons there's some examples of what you want.